# Collapsed nav has no background

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a working responsive navbar on my website but for some reason I can't add a background to it, any help?

```js
$(".navigation-toggle").click(function() {
  $("li").toggleClass("navigation-open");
});
```

```css
 body{
  background-color: red;
 }


.navigation {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 70px;
}
.navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navigation a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 24px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation-name {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.navigation-toggle {
  display: none;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
.navigation-open {
  display: block !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navigation li {
    display: none;
  }
  .navigation-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navigation">
  <button class="navigation-toggle">☰</button>
  <a class="navigation-name" href="#">Architect</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Examples</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Im looking to add a plain white background to the li elements but as I said I can't.

---

**Original sass code below:**

```css
.navigation
    background-color: #fff
    height: 70px
    ul
        list-style-type: none
        margin: 0
        padding: 0
        overflow: hidden
        background-color: #fff
    li
        display: inline-block

    a
        display: block
        color: #000
        text-align: center
        padding: 24px 16px
        text-decoration: none

.navigation-name
    float: left
    height: 50px
    padding: 10px 25px
    font-size: 18px
    text-decoration: none
    font-weight: bold

.navigation-toggle
    display: none
    font-size: 34px
    font-weight: bold
    position: relative
    float: right
    padding: 6px 12px
    margin-top: 0px
    margin-right: 15px
    margin-bottom: 0px
    background-color: transparent
    background-image: none
    border: 1px solid transparent
    border-radius: 4px
    cursor: pointer
    outline: none

.navigation-open
    display: block !important
    background-color: #fff
    text-align: center
    margin: 0 auto





@media (max-width : 768px)
    .navigation 
        li
            display: none

    .navigation-toggle
        display: block
```

Comment: try adding  curly brackets in css like
.navigation{
    background-color: #fff
    height: 70px
    ul{
        list-style-type: none
        margin: 0
        padding: 0
        overflow: hidden
        background-color: #fff
}
    li{
        display: inline-block
}
    a{
        display: block
        color: #000
        text-align: center
        padding: 24px 16px
        text-decoration: none
}
}

Comment: Hi your css is incorrect, any class needs to look like this .yourclass {attribute:value}. You're missing your curly brackets.

Comment: I use SASS @NathanielFlick

Comment: @Zoid you need to create a js fiddle with your actual, correct, rendered code i order for us to help you. Cheers. Even SASS has the curly brackets in it, yours does not, which is why your styles aren't being applied.

Comment: SASS doesnt use brackets, SCSS does. @NathanielFlick

Comment: Well.. it's white... one white here. Perhaps at least change the coloring for the question??

Comment: @Zoid fair enough, but the rendered css most definitely requires the curly brackets.

Comment: changed bg colour but on SO it has a white backgorund but on my local site is doesnt? WTF

Comment: You need to set width: 100% for the navigation drop down menu. Looking at your code further, it's overly complex. I would have set navigation-open as an absolutely positioned element. Not sure why you didn't in this case?

Comment: Tried that and it doesnt work @NathanielFlick